# Is there a simple method to import data from multiple excel flies to SQL including names of the files using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I need to import salary data from multiple excel files where filename of each file is a date.

I used SSIS and with success followed typical tutorials for importing multiple excel files. The thing is none of them show simple method how to add one extra column (with the name of the file) to the result. There are some tutorials with huge code scripts, that are too complicated for me.

What I did was to add 'Derived column' module between typical 'excel source' and 'OLE BD destination' where I added a new column 'date' with expression @[User::FileName] - a variable that is used for 'foreach loop container' but as a result I received corectly combined data from all files but the extra column contains the same data - the filename of the first imported file.

I wonder if there is any simple to make the variable I used to change with every loop ? So, as a result, I receive combined data plus one extra column containing the corresponding date, which is the name of each file. Many Thanks

Comment: Is the `User::FileName` variable being set by the `Foreach Loop Container`? If so, this should be picked up by the `Data Flow Task`.

Comment: No, the variable is used by '   Foreach Loop Container', It would be great if the container could create any variables so it could be picked up by the Data Flow Task

Comment: Are you using a `Foreach File Enumerator`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I've posted an answer which should do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a `Foreach File Enumerator`, select "Name only" in the `Collection` pane as in the image below (I'm assuming that "Name only" will give you the date that you are looking for).

[image: Collection Pane]

This allows you to map this into a variable on each iteration. To do this, navigate to the `Variable Mappings` pane, and select the variable you want to use in your `Data Flow Task`, with 0 as the Index.

[image: Variable Mappings Pane]

You can then add this variable as a `Derived Column`, and it will give you the name of the file you are importing.

Comment: That's it !! This is a simple solution! Thanks!

Comment: If you are using name only (vs fully qualified), how are you setting the connection string to the spreadsheet?

Comment: I typically go fully qualified. then do a right( variable , findstring(reverse(variable),"/")

Comment: Good question. Although as the data flow was already working without setting the variable I figured this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: A good comment to have on here though, as that would probably be the way it would be done in most cases. :)